# Create page navigation in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently building a website that dynamically generates content into the index.html page, with option to filter. The problem is when it's not filtered, there could be up to 300 items. I would like to create a page navigation (like Yelp) that would let the user scroll to the next page after 10 items.

index.html

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

load.js

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
for (var i=0; i<somthing.length; i++) {
   var info = document.createElement('div');
   info.className = "infobox";
   info.textContent = "This is content #" + i;
   content.appendChild(info);
}
```

Now my HTML should have all the generated content, but it would be a nightmare to scroll past this. How would I cut this down and have the option to navigate thru pages?

Comment: You got to think about the feasibility of having the server return 300 items of content when you only need 10 to begin with. It might be better to just return what needs to be displayed and return the rest when the paginator is used. Having said that, there's quite a few tutorials on how to paginate through a collection of objects. Here's one that covers the basics: http://www.thatsoftwaredude.com/content/6125/how-to-paginate-through-a-collection-in-javascript

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short pagination solution that should work:

```html
<html>
<script>
  function init() {
    var pageSize = 15;
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    for (var i = 0; i < 300;) {
      // Create page container
      var page = document.createElement('div');
      content.appendChild(page);
      // Hide all content after first page
      if (i >= pageSize) page.style.display = "none";
      for (;;) {
        var info = document.createElement('div');
        info.className = "infobox";
        info.textContent = "This is content #" + i;
        page.appendChild(info);
        // Quit when page size is reached
        if (i++ % pageSize == (pageSize - 1)) break;
      }
      // Create 'more' button
      var more = document.createElement('a');
      more.href = '#';
      more.textContent = "more...";
      more.onclick = function(e) {
        this.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
        this.style.display = "none";
      }
      page.appendChild(more);
      content = page;
    }
  }
</script>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```